# Assigning variables to a range in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run the following algorithm in R:

1. generate a uniform random variable, u
2. find F(x(i-1)) < u <= F(x(i))
3. return x=x(i)

In my case, I segmented my F(x) so that it is given by:

```
cdf:
[1] 0.0000000000 0.0001524158 0.0025910684 0.0196616369 0.0879439110 
    0.2586495961 0.5317786923 0.8049077884 0.9609815577 1.0000000000
```

So for example F(x(1)) = cdf[2]

Then i generate a vector of random uniforms:

```
 u<-c(runif(10000,0,1))
```

But I am having trouble assigning each element in that vector to a specific range in the 'cdf'. I've tried a for loop with many if statements, but this is tedious and error prone.

I've also tried the following using a while statement:

```
 x<-u
 for(i in (1:length(u))){
   for(j in (1:length(cdf)))
      while(x[i]<cdf[j]){x[i]==which(cdf[j]>=x[i])}
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `cut()`, as in:

```
cutPoints  <-  c(0.0000000000,# could set to -1.  See comment below.
                0.0001524158,
                0.0025910684,
                0.0196616369,
                0.0879439110,
                0.2586495961,
                0.5317786923,
                0.8049077884,
                0.9609815577,
                1.0000000000)
u  <-  runif(1000)
cut(u,
    cutPoints,
    labels = seq.int(length(cutPoints)-1))
```

Notice that the length of the (optional) argument `labels` is one less than the cut points b/c the labels label the space between the cut points.  See `?cut` for details.

Comment: You might want to set `cutPoints[1] <- -1` since `cut` does not include the left of the range. (Try `cut(0, cutPoints)` to see my point.)

Comment: @r2evans  I see your point.  (See added comment in response).  However, (to be obnoxiously technical) the probability that `runif()` returns a zero is `.Machine$$double.xmin` which is `2.225074e-308` on my machine which is practically zero....

Comment: So you're saying there's a chance ... (I considered it ... and commented anyway, perhaps partly because I was 3 seconds away from posting my own answer ;-) )

Comment: Cool, It's actually a good comment b/c (in my experience) a lot of people [myself included at times] use `min(u)` as `cutPoints[1]` and get all confused when there are missing values in the vector returned by `cut()`...  (oh, ya, and I caught the Dumb and Dumber reference...)

Comment: when i run the code with the labels, i get an error that the breaks length and labels length is not the same. I ran it without labels, so this assigns each element of u into one of the ranges in cutPoints. What I was hoping to do was to assign each element in u to the index of the interval, so for example interval (0.532,0.805] would correspond to a value of 6.

Comment: Oops.  I made a fix to the labels argument (see response).